# SQL how to use minus or !=

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions

I have a database with a few thousand parts.  I am attempting to find how many parts are no longer carried at our store.

```
select count(distinct part_no) 
from parts
where status = '1111'
```

I get the correct number of parts that we are carrying.  However when I try the following I get the total number of parts listed in the database.

```
select count(distinct part_no)
from parts
where status != '1111'
```

I've also tried using minus but that doesn't seem to run at all

```
select count(part_no)
from parts
minus
select count(part_no)
from parts
where status = '1111'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
select count(part_no) 
from parts
where status = '1111'
Group By part_no
```

Comment: Can it be done with the !=...I cannot figure out why it is returning the total number of parts when I put != in?

Comment: @Fstagger Yes, `!=` should have worked too.  Can you post your table with a little data?  Do you get nothing with `=` and everything with `!=`?  If so, it could be that you have no status of `1111`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select status , count(distinct part_no)
from parts
where status != '1111'
```